# Is it possible to modify the 'system bookmarks' category in the file browser?

Tags: file-browser

I was just playing around with the latest build of Blender 2.8 and downloaded some files from the internet to check out Eevee with. I wanted to open the file from my downloads folder and noticed it is not a default bookmark, although there is a 'System Bookmarks' folder in the file browser, and most OSes have a system download folder.

[image]

It doesn't seem to be possible to add bookmarks to 'System Bookmarks', so I added my download folder to the 'Bookmarks' folder instead. I know there is a bookmarks.txt file in the Blender config folder, but it doesn't contain the System Bookmarks category and trying to add one to it doesn't work. Is it possible to modify system bookmarks somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't find a way to directly modify System Bookmarks, the most recent versions of Blender (2.81 and above) include an option in the Preferences that allow you to hide both the System and Recent bookmarks, which are both auto-generated bookmark types.

The options can be found in Preferences under Save & Load. Check 'Hide System Bookmarks' to hide the from the file browser. You can also use 'Hide Recent Locations' if you don't like to see recent file browser history.

[image]

This does not answer the question originally asked, but it does solve the issue I was having with the bookmark sidebar having space wasted by bookmarks I didn't use.